# Spring Boot Rest template Mocking : ResponseEntity.getBody() throws a Null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to JUnit and Mockito. Here I am trying to mock the rest template call and return a response entity. But it throws me a Null pointer Exception. I am not able to figure out what's wrong with the mocking. Can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong?

**JUnit5 Unit test cases**

```
class MyTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private MyService service;

   @Mock
   private RestTemplate template;

   @BeforeEach
   void setUp(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
   }
   private ResponseEntity<String> generateResponse(String body, HttpStatus http) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(body, http);
   }

   @Test
   public void publishEventsuccessResponseTest() {

      when(template.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
      ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())).thenReturn(generateResponse("uuid", 
      HttpStatus.OK));
      String result = service.sentData("data");
      Assertions.assertTrue("uuid".equals(result));
   }
}
```

**Service**

```
    class MyService {
    
    
       public String sentData(String data) {
    
         String jsonResp = "";
         ResponseEntity<String> response;
    
         try {
             HttpEntity<String> requestBody = new HttpEntity<String>(data, headers);
             response = restTemplate.postForEntity("url", requestBody, String.class);
         } catch (Exception ex) {}
    
         System.out.println(response); //value : Null
    
         if (response.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) { // Null pointer exception
               jsonResp = response.getBody();
         }
      return jsonResp;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `@BeforeEach` to `@Before` of jUnit4 and add `public void setUp()`

Your test should be green!